# Unable to insert into MS Access due to an "SQL Syntax" error

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to do an insert into MS Access, but I get an error in "SQL Syntax".

I believe the word "password" is a keyword. Is there a way to work around this without changing the database field name?

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO profiles(
     user_name, full_name, password, profile_id) 
     VALUES (@user_name, @full_name, @password, @profile_id);");

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", this.FullName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name", this.UserName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", this.Password);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profile_id", this.ProfileID);
```

EDIT:

There was a typo in the code above, which I have now fixed. It did not appear in the original code, but appeared after I edited it for here. The fix, as many pointed out was the brackets.

Comment: `YouAreSalty` have you spot checked your Insert Statement if you are adding a parameter it's name(s) must match this is a no brainer

Comment: @DJKRAZE Not in OleDb they don't.  Only the order of the parameters matter.

Comment: `LarsTech` good point.. I am so use to using OracleParams and SqlParams that I really didn't think it mattered.. good catch

Comment: @Grant Winney Will do for next time. I knew what the problem was, but I suppose sometimes what I "know" might be wrong....

Comment: I think this is a valid question, if the op fixes his code sample.  Access is not as lenient as other sql environments, and knowing that brackets around column names that are the same as keywords may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the database field in quotes or square brackets:

`[password]`
`"password"`

e.g.:

```
"INSERT INTO profiles(user_name, full_name, [password], profile_id)
```

Comment: That's not the issue here.

Comment: @KenWhite, given the code the OP has shown, and the error being a `SQL Syntax` error, that's the only place it could be.  Anything else would require more code to accurately reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ps2goat Grant pointed out the actual problem in his comment

Comment: there are 2 problems in the `OP's` case.. perhaps the OP themselves did not spot check their own query string.. `@password and @passwords`

Comment: The issue in the OP's post is a typo between `password` and `@passwords`. I didn't say your answer was wrong (which is why I didn't downvote); I just noted that it's not the issue here, because adding those brackets won't resolve the problem.

Comment: The main issue is indeed the lack of brackets. The typo was simply a copy and edit error that was not in the original code, but appeared while editing here. Thanks!

Comment: @GrantWinney Yeah. That was the real issue. The other typo issue was just me editing the unecessary portion out accidentally adding it in. In my original code, it does not appear there.

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the field name in square brackets.

The mismatch between between *@passwords* and *@password* is irrelevant because the parameter names are ignored when using OleDb with Access.  However you *must* supply the parameter values in the same order as they appear in the `INSERT` statement --- so *@user_name* before *@full_name*:

```
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO profiles(user_name, full_name, [password], profile_id) VALUES (@user_name, @full_name, @passwords, @profile_id);");

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name", this.UserName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@full_name", this.FullName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", this.Password);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profile_id", this.ProfileID);
```

Judging by the comments, it appears we have a disagreement as to whether *password* is a reserved word in MS Access.  According to Microsoft, it is a reserved word: [List of reserved words in Jet 4.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738)

Comment: does the order really matter? I'd think that ADO.NET would be smart enough to rearrange the parameters.

Comment: Yes, since OleDb (with MS Access) ignores the parameter *names*, it can only use their position to match parameter values with the parameter "place-holders" in the SQL statement.